# gdallocationinfo used in javascript with node-gdal?

Tags: raster, gdal, javascript, html, node-gdal

I cannot figure it out if it's possible to get pixel information from my rasters using `gdallocationinfo` in `javascript`. I found [node-gdal](https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal), but after reading its documentation I'm not sure if `gdallocationinfo` is usable.

I basically need this:

```
gdallocationinfo mytiff.vrt lonlat.lon lonlat.lat -valonly -geoloc
```

So I added to my javascript the following as a test (after node-gdal was succesfully installed as explained in the link above):

```
var gdal = require("gdal");
var dataset = gdal.open("mytiff.vrt");
console.log("number of bands: " + dataset.bands.count());
console.log("width: " + dataset.rasterSize.x);
console.log("height: " + dataset.rasterSize.y);
console.log("geotransform: " + dataset.geoTransform);
console.log("srs: " + (ds.srs ? ds.srs.toWKT() : 'null'));
```

but I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

It seems to me that node-gdal is not being recognized, do I need to add some kind of src path to my HTML file first to get node-gdal working?

Comment: node-gdal is only meant for [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) (which runs server-side, not client-side)

Answer (score 1):

Five rows solution:

```
var dataset = gdal.open('mytiff.vrt');
var band = dataset.bands.get(1);
var coordinateTransform = new gdal.CoordinateTransformation(gdal.SpatialReference.fromEPSG(4326), dataset);
var pt = coordinateTransform.transformPoint(lonlat.lon, lonlat.lat);
console.log(band.pixels.get(pt.x, pt.y));
```